# Need help to assign ringtones for different contacts

Tags: iphone

From my application i want to change the following settings of iphone :

- I want to set the separate ringtones against individual contacts in iphone.
- I want to set ringtone volumes against any contacts

Can I do these from my application?
Please help me to find the procedure as i am a totally newbie to this new technology of iPhone.
Thanks for your help in advance.
Ritz

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to set/alter ringtone settings via the published iOS SDK (there are most likely "private" methods, but using these will result in your app being rejected), as otherwise any errant application could trivially make irritating changes.

i.e.: Only the user can change the ringtone settings.