# Assign ringtone to contact or group of contacts in iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios7, abaddressbook, addressbookui

I checked the documentation but could not find anywhere regarding assigning ringtone to a group of contacts programmatically. I was wondering is it even possible without using Private API and app store safe ?

My question is the duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164663/need-help-to-assign-ringtones-for-different-contacts) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283099/programmatically-access-add-change-ringtones-of-contacts) but I checked this [application](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/gurupu-zhe-xin-yin-she-ding/id523481550?mt=8), and it does what I was looking for so may be I am overlooking the documentation ?

Any insight on this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to assign contact or group of contact pragmatically for App Store app but you can quietly do for jaibreak app.

Comment: Have you checked [this application](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/gurupu-zhe-xin-yin-she-ding/id523481550?mt=8) which does that ? and it is on the store right now !! which is my question.

Comment: How is the GRingtones app able to do it??

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this.. [Is it possible to set the ringtone file(name) for a phone number in a contact using codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060880/is-it-possible-to-set-the-ringtone-filename-for-a-phone-number-in-a-contact-us)

Old post but still valid In short --

`Apple will not allow any Application in app store which modifies user preferences..`

Comment: Have you checked [this application](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/gurupu-zhe-xin-yin-she-ding/id523481550?mt=8) which does that ? and it is on the store right now !! which is my question.

Comment: @JanakNirmal have you installed this app on device and checked? I doubt whether it actually works or not also The same app has iPad version as well now what the hack ringtone has a purpose on iPad when we can't call from iPad?

Comment: I have downloaded the free version of this app and tested. It works according as it claims.

Comment: Guys any update on it? How does it work?? Everyone is saying it's not possible but this app is able to do it

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically this is not allowed as per Apple guidelines because you are not allowed to change user preferences through a separate program. That's simply it is. This is specially true for groups since user doesn't have a way to revert the changes done through your program without his permission.

However, the program you have specified here might be using Address Book API methods to retrieve the group they want to change and modifying the ringtone information through a system command by allowing the current user to be root or admin. Just a thought if it can be done.